# GUI in DrRacket running slow on laptop (low FPS)

Tags: performance, scheme, gpu, racket, game-physics

for a project i have to remake the game "Donkey Kong", i have done most of it, but for some reason the game is slow "laggy" on my gaming laptop (10-40 FPS). On my desktop computer it runs fine (+100fps). Is there a way i can fix this?
The processor on the laptop is almost twice as fast as the one on the desktop, and the laptop has 2GPU's an integrated and a dedicated one. Thanks.

Comment: And this is when running compiled code and not run from DrRacket?

Comment: Same operating system?

Comment: Precompute all images you can (e.g. if your code uses `(flip-image-horizontally donkey-kong-image)` then store the result and use the same image each time rather than recomputing it every frame.

Comment: @Sylwester I use the run from DrRacket

Comment: @soegaard desktop win7, laptop win10 but i have tried it on other win10 desktops and it works fine

Comment: @KillerZ224 Which version of DrRacket?

Comment: @soegaard the only image i recompute every frame is mario, i'm trying to get rid of that aswell.

Comment: @soegaard Racket v6.10.1

Comment: @KillerZ224 Try version 6.12  http://download.racket-lang.org/

Comment: In that case you should compare the language settings since the dynamic properties might be different or I would have tried "create executabe' to see if it changed the speed.

Comment: As @Sylwester says, you should get a significant speed boost when running in DrRacket from disabling debugging annotation, done in the "Show Details..." subpanel of the "Language > Choose Language" menu. Running from the command-line could potentially speed things up, as well.

Comment: Also, I'd love to try it out, if you decide to publish it in a GitHub repo or in some other way!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I actually had the 6.12 version on DrRacket on my laptop, I tried downgrading to 6.10 and this fixed the lag.

Comment: @KillerZ224 if downgrading fixes the problem, there might be a bug in Racket. Please file a bug report (include code if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! I actually had the 6.12 version on DrRacket on my laptop, I tried downgrading to 6.10 and this fixed the lag.